# find files on Linux which have capabilities set

Tags: linux, security, find

I could copy `/bin/cat` to `/tmp/test` and run `sudo setcap cap_dac_read_search+ep /tmp/test`. And then I'll have a file which can read any other file (e.g. `/etc/shadow`).

How could I search the filesystem for files which have capabilities set, to see if any such files have been created already?

Answer (score 5):

You'd use [`getcap`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/getcap) (as the name `setcap` suggests).

```
$ getcap -r /
/bin/foo = cap_bar+ep
/usr/bin/bar = cap_foo+eip
```